# Using regex in bash to find files

Tags: regex, bash, shell, scripting

Basically what I am trying to do is list the contents of the current directory that has a certain extension (in my case .c files).

So what I thought would work is:

```
ls | grep .\*\.c
```

And it mainly works but also returns files that end in c like

1. music (which is a directory)
2. test.doc

Is there a problem with my regex because I cannot see it.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to escape your backslash:

```
ls | grep .*\\.c
```

Comment: many thanks for this. works perfectly. may i ask why you need to escape the backslash? from my understanding that regex means _0 or more of anything followed by \ followed by one of anything followed by c_. Am I missing something here!

Comment: @djjavo normally in bash a backslash means "escape the next character", so to use an actual backslash for your regex you need to escape it.

Comment: yes i understand the \ being the escape character but i do not understand why we need to use an actual backslash in the regular expression (as its somecode.c not somecode\.c) am i being stupid because i do not understand!?

Comment: in regular expressions, a `.` matches any character, so you have to escape the `.` to match an actual `.`

Comment: yes i know that, but is you have "\\" then you are escaping the escape character??

Comment: That will also match "file.cookie.txt" because you're just looking for a dot followed by a "c"

Comment: @glenn jackman ah ok so the \\ is preventing this? sorry - misread the 2nd comment by mVChr - that explains it clearly - thanks, issue solved :)

Comment: @djjavo, look for Julien May's correct answer: if you want to find files **ending** with ".c", you have to provide the end-of-string anchor.

Answer (score 4):

You can simply use `ls *.c` to list all files in the current directory having `.c` extension.

Comment: thanks for that andrew - did not know this. sorry if i wasn't clear in the question, but i would prefer to use ls | grep. many thanks for the help though, it is much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3):

Here's what you can do:

```
find -name "*.c"
```

and it will find all files with the `.c` extension for you, recursively from the current working directory.

Alternatively, if you want non-recursive and want to do it with `ls`, you can do:

```
ls *.c
```

If you want to know how to apply regex with `grep` to a `ls` search result (even though this is more cumbersome):

```
ls | grep ".*\.c$"
```

Regexplanation:

- `.` - match any character
- `.*` - match any character zero or more times
- `.*\.` - match any character zero or more times, then match a `.` literally (specified by "escaping" it with `\`)
- `".*\.c` - match any character zero or more times, then match a `.` literally, then match the char `c`
- `.*\.c$` - match any character zero or more times, then match a `.` literally, then match the char `c`; and only if that is the end of the pattern (there are no more things after that). `$` is the regex anchor for "the end".

Comment: to mention that find searches recursively.

Answer (score 2):

you are pretty close

```
ls | grep \\.c$
```

see the double backslashs